# Sufficiency in A Strict Inequality Relationship

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

Let $a=b\times c$ and $d=e\times f$.

Suppose $a>d$.

Then, the sufficient condition is $b>e,c>f.$

Is a necessary condition $b>e$ or $c>f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. Proof by contrapositive.

Assume $b\leq e$ **and** $c\leq f$. Then, $a=bc\leq fe=d$ with equality if and only if $b=e$ and $c=f$. Therefore, $a\leq d$, which was to be shown.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Can you also respond to the question whether the necessary condition is either one of the two?

Comment: Yes. It is necessary to have $b>e$ or $c>f$. This is exactly what I prove.